# Editing Content Assist (not template)?

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

This is the code that's generated through Content Assist for creating an anonymous-inner class

```
new ActionListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
```

It's a small thing, but I wanted to edit the template so that the `//TODO` message isn't there. I can't find it in templates, and I was wondering if there was another place to edit the generated code in Content Assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The templates are in **Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates**. What you want to alter is in **Code -> Method body**.